# Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN error

Tags: node.js, heroku

I recently updates ssl certificates on my heroku server.
I am getting this error when scheduler.js task runs.

I raised ticket on herlu but sadly no response.

stack trace

```
Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1283:32) at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17) at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:896:10) at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:430:15) at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:294:10) at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:344:25) at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:211:10) at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:201:5) at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:172:11) at write (_stream_readable.js:547:24)
```

Answer (score 0):

as I found [here](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/issues/182) - check if you have anti-virus blocking some needed certificates.

if not, check also this thread:
[Npm SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099098/npm-self-signed-cert-in-chain-on-azure)

suggesting to upgrade npm:

```
npm update -g
```

or

```
npm config set ca ""
```

if neither works, try maybe to downgrade your node.js version...