# ERROR: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN using localhost

Tags: node.js, certificate, npm, antivirus, nodemailer

I got an error when using nodemailer on localhost, causing an internal server error (500):
ERROR: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

I found this thread on the issue:
[Npm SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099098/npm-self-signed-cert-in-chain-on-azure), suggesting to do:

```
npm config set ca ""
```

but didn't help. also upgrading the npm didn't help:

```
npm update -g
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

so just when I was about the downgrade my node.js (version 10.32) I found this thread:

[SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN while launching server](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/issues/182)

suggesting **IT'S THE ANTI-VIRUS!!!** that is blocking some needed certificates.

after disabling the anti-virus, it worked!

Comment: good call, this really tripped me up since I read this error shows up due to an outdated NPM.  Turns out that had nothing to do with it.  In my case I'm using Avast and I had to disable that for it to work.

Answer (score 10):

Disable antivirus "Outbound email scan" SMTP

wanted a way to leave my anti-virus running, and so just disabled the
SMTP scan on Avast and all works.
Am sure there is a better way, but this works.

Answer (score 7):

**This is the Node.js recipe to solve this issue:**

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';
```

Reference - https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/357

Comment: I exported in the terminal and work fine for me!  For development purposes solved ;).